# Error TNS-12541: TNS:no listener but Windows TNS Listener Services is Started

Tags: database, oracle11g, listener, tnsnames, tns

Somehow, our database instance is not able to connect to the database instance when no any Oracle server files were modified, listed below :

Database Instance : UP, Listener : DOWN, Agent Connection to Instance : DOWN

The version is Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1)

When run this command using sql plus :

```
select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';
```

The output is : **orcl1**

Here's my listener.ora (D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN) :

```
LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXDS1)(PORT = 1521))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
  )
 )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = c:\Oracle
```

tnsnames.ora :

```
ORCL1 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.12)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SID = ORCL1)
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL1)
  )
 )
```

log.xml for the first error occured :

```
<msg time='2021-02-20T09:19:24.203+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>20-FEB-2021 09:19:24 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=XXXDS1$))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl1)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.12)(PORT=56955)) * establish * orcl1 * 12560
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T09:19:34.343+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
 64-bit Windows Error: 53: Unknown error
  TNS-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
  TNS-12571: TNS:packet writer failure
   TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
   TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
    64-bit Windows Error: 54: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Another error from log.xml :

```
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:51:15.390+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>20-FEB-2021 10:51:15 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl1)(CID=(PROGRAM=D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emagent.exe)(HOST=XXXDS1)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.12)(PORT=49401)) * establish * orcl1 * 12505
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:51:25.514+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:51:42.490+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>20-FEB-2021 10:51:35 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl1)(CID=(PROGRAM=D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\perl\bin\perl.exe)(HOST=XXXDS1)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=::1)(PORT=49406)) * establish * orcl1 * 12505
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:51:52.614+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:52:02.738+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>20-FEB-2021 10:52:02 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=XXXDS1$))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl1)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.12)(PORT=49408)) * establish * orcl1 * 12514
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:52:12.862+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Another error from log.xml :

```
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:53:40.705+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>TNS-12571: TNS:packet writer failure
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
  64-bit Windows Error: 54: Unknown error
  TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2021-02-20T10:53:50.844+07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='XXXDS1'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>Dynamic address is already listened on (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXXDS1.xxxad.local)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
```

These error was written several times

The lsnrctl status is **READY**

How can this case suddenly happen and how to fix it?

Sincerely,

Oviedityanto

Comment: "Dynamic address is already listened on" - it looks like something else is already using port 1521.

Comment: @pmdba , it's listened on (HOST=XXXDS1.xxxad.local) and my listener.ora is (HOST = XXXDS1). Is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke I found the answer

My listener.log file is 4Gb. So I changed the file name, restart services and it works.
Speed performance when open enterprise manager increased too.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My version is 11.2
Oracle does not explicitly say that the log file size can be a problem. This took 2 1/2 years to occur. That can be more or less depending on your setup and traffic. Our connections are dynamic, so there are log entries written continuously.
Stop database servers and the listener service.
Change to the log directory, for us that is:
\oracle\diag\tnslsnr<hostname>\listener\trace

in our case is just our Windows server.
At that point, we moved the listener.log to a different drive, although we could have just deleted it. Then restart the listener and then the database servers.